# Terraform aws_spot_instance_request being recreated in every apply

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I am new to Terraform and I've successfully created spot instances using aws_spot_instance_request. The only problem is that they are being recreated (and so my ec2 spot instances), in every apply. Any hint on that? Tks! **id** and **metadata_options** force recreation (see below).

Terraform v0.11.14 | provider.aws v2.60.0

```
resource "aws_spot_instance_request" "machine_host" {
  count                = 2
  ami                  = "${var.machine_ami}"
  key_name             = "${var.key_name}"
  instance_type        = "${var.machine_instance_type}"
  iam_instance_profile = "${var.aws_iam_instance_profile_id}"
  monitoring           = "${var.use_detailed_monitoring}"

  wait_for_fulfillment            = true
  instance_interruption_behaviour = "stop"

  root_block_device {
    volume_size           = "${var.volume_size}"
    volume_type           = "${var.volume_type}"
    delete_on_termination = true
  }

  vpc_security_group_ids = [
    "${element(data.aws_security_groups.sg1.ids, 0)}",
    "${element(data.aws_security_groups.sg2.ids, 0)}",
  ]

  subnet_id = "${element(data.aws_subnet_ids.private.ids, 0)}"

  tags = "${merge(
    local.common_tags,
    local.system_tags,
    map(
      "Name", "${var.machine_name}-${var.environment_name}-${count.index}",
      "Type", "${var.machine_name}",
      "Resource", "ec2",
    )
  )}"


  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "../../files/update_spotinstance_tags.sh ${var.aws_region} ${self.id} ${self.spot_instance_id}"
  }
}


> -/+ module.backend.aws_spot_instance_request.machine_host[1] (new resource required)
>       id:                                        "sir-ht6sgc1h" => <computed> (forces new resource)
>       ami:                                       "ami-b70554c8" => "ami-b70554c8"
>       arn:                                       "" => <computed>
>       associate_public_ip_address:               "false" => <computed>
>       availability_zone:                         "" => <computed>
>       cpu_core_count:                            "" => <computed>
>       cpu_threads_per_core:                      "" => <computed>
>       ebs_block_device.#:                        "0" => <computed>
>       ephemeral_block_device.#:                  "0" => <computed>
>       get_password_data:                         "false" => "false"
>       host_id:                                   "" => <computed>
>       iam_instance_profile:                      "dev-email-backend" =>
> "dev-email-backend"
>       instance_interruption_behaviour:           "stop" => "stop"
>       instance_state:                            "" => <computed>
>       instance_type:                             "t3.micro" => "t3.micro"
>       ipv6_address_count:                        "0" => <computed>
>       ipv6_addresses.#:                          "0" => <computed>
>       key_name:                                  "backend-email-stg" => "backend-email-stg"
>       metadata_options.#:                        "" => <computed> (forces new resource)
>       monitoring:                                "false" => "false"
```

Comment: Since this is a request and not the actual instance itself, the API ID will likely be unique for each invocation. I am unsure if the instance ID can be tied to the request ID in the state for idempotence.

Comment: What is funny is that the Spot Request ID, due to persistent = true will be the same, but I think Terraform can't compute (foresee) that.

Comment: I want to know what version number of terraform-provider-aws you are using.

Comment: Terraform v0.11.14 | provider.aws v2.60.0  I couldn't migrate to v0.12 as yet.

Comment: Hi, just wanna let you know that I've tested today Terraform v0.12.24 and this was solved.